# My Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5801) is not being detected by my PC -- What should I do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo, usb-connection-mode

I have a Samsung Galaxy 3 ([GT-i5801](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_i5800)) Android phone. Currently, my phone is not being detected by my PC. Initially, when I purchased this phone, I was developing applications and I was able to run the applications on my phone. I have purchased a new cable as I thought the data cable may have been damaged, but that did not solve the issue.

What can be the possible solutions or what do I need to check for in order to connect my Samsung Galaxy 3 to my PC by using a data/USB cable?

I have Windows XP installed on my [Dell Inspiron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron) laptop.

Comment: there is no need for the exclamation marks, imo.

Comment: Can you tell us what was the message or any other information?

Comment: @Louis Rhys usb device not recognized message is being coming up when i try to connect !! I think i am trying to connect with USB cable so no need to install driver

Comment: I have similar problem with Samsung Galaxy 3, i5801. Initially mount dialog was appearing but now it is not. it just charge mobile.

Do that dialog requires any specific service or program, which might have be uninstalled accidently?

In settings-about phone-usb settings- mass storage option is enabled, also tried with ask on connection but no luck.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching for a long time and trying a lot, I found a solution:

### Resolution

1. Unplug the USB cable
2. On the cell phone, dial the number `*#7284#`.
   Once the last `#` is hit, the PhoneUtil application is launched. Choose *USB* -> *Modem* and then *USB* -> *PDA mode*. The good mode should be PDA. Even if the mode is PDA, switch to Modem and then back to PDA.

   1. Also choose **UART** -> PDA and then **UART** -> MODEM mode. The good mode should be MODEM for **UART**. Even if the mode is MODEM, switch to PDA and then back to MODEM(**UART**).
3. Plug in the USB cable.

### Note:

This is not only for Samsung Galaxy 3 - Android phone, but it is also used to repair the USB connection for any Samsung Android phone.

Comment: A thousand Thanks to Paresh Mayani for the *#7284# tip. USB connection stopped working on my new Galaxy 3 and all Samsung Customer Support suggested was to do a factory reset. I expect that would have solved the problem, but at the expense of losing all my personal settings.

So thumbs up for Paresh and thumbs down for Samsung Customer Support!

Comment: @Michael Thanx for the kind words, i was in same situation as you are, later on i found this solution so i shared it here. Samsung Customer Support had told me for the Factory Reset, what a majak they had done!! They should have atleast know about this *#7284#

Comment: I am having same problem again but this time this solution doesnt work ... any other idea ???

Comment: @PareshMayani I have a galaxy s3 and installed paranoid android 4.5 ( kitkat 4.4.4 ), but *#7284# does not show anything!

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your device is not connected to your PC.
2. Uninstall any drivers you currently have installed for it.
3. Reboot your computer.
4. Install the appropriate drivers from this XDA post (supports more than Galaxy S) http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=7238660&postcount=1
5. Install Kies from Samsung.com's Galaxy 3 page http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=23020100&prd_mdl_cd=GT-I5800DKAXEU&prd_mdl_name=GT-I5800
6. Connect your device to your PC.

Comment: thanx for the support, but as i am connecting Mobile with PC by using USB Cable, i haven't install any driver for the same. And ya, i have installed kies from the CD came with the samsung-galaxy-3 purchased box

Comment: As you have mentioned link for installing driver, it is for Samsung Galaxy S , not for Galaxy 3, check it: http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x86.shtml , what should i do ??

Comment: I recommend uninstalling the version of Kies that came on your CD, since it is likely outdated, and using the version on Samsung's download page.  And as I mentioned in my post, the drivers actually support many Samsung devices and not just the Galaxy S, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you were previously developing on your PC, do you have USB Debugging enabled on your phone? That uses a whole different set of drivers than the normal USB drivers, these drivers are available as part of the Android SDK download.

To check if you have USB Debugging enabled, go into **Settings** -> **Applications** -> **Development** -> **USB Debugging** and take the tick out of the USB Debugging box.

If you turn off USB Debugging, then it should be able to connect to your PC using the standard USB mass storage device drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Per userguide after you connected the USB cable on Mass Storage mode, you need to go to the shortcut/notification/USB cable connected then mount.

Comment: Ya it is, but before it was raising when i purchased the phone, but now no such notification comes , just battery is recharging

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I still had my PALM synchronization software installed. For some reason or another, it used COMM port 4 for it's communication ( don't know why but it did ), and that conflicted ( probably behind the scenes ) with the communication with my Galaxy S.

Once I uninstalled the PALM synchronization software, the connection went fine.

So please check if on your pc some sort of other communication device is installed.