# Unable to mount Galaxy S2 on Debian Squeeze laptop as storage device

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, mount

I am trying to mount my Galaxy S2 on Debian Squeeze laptop. I turned off USB debugging and then in:

```
"Wireless & Networks" → "USB Utilities" → "Connect storage to PC"
```

it asks me to connect a USB cable, as soon as I connect the USB cable the pop goes away and my phone starts charging but I don't see my phone mounted in my laptop.

I did `lsusb` and don't see any Samsung device connected. Then I decided to turn on USB debugging and did `lsusb` again but no luck. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment helped me, though I also had to create a udev rule https://android.stackexchange.com/a/5067/11156, the udev rule is given below, please note that kumar is my username on my box.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="6640", MODE="0660", OWNER="kumar",
GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: If this solution solved your issue, consider accepting the answer to have the question answered.