# Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5801) is not being detected in Kies

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-kies, usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-apollo

Whenever I connect my device to my PC, it asks me on connection for the type of connection I want. If I select Samsung kies in the device it shows me connected, but in the kies it keeps connecting *(with spinner...)*.

I have tried the solutions described on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4322/16265) answers, but no avail.

The problem from the mentioned question is different from what I'm experiencing, so I ask your ideas about this?

## Relevant details

Device

> Device : Samsung Galaxy i5801;
> OS : android 2.2;
> Baseband version : I5801DDJP2;
> Build Number : FROYO.DDJP6;
> Kernel Version : 2.6.32.9.

kies Information

> Interestingly when i go to help section of kies and click on kies information it freezes with some semi transparent layer on it so cant find its version *(need to close it from task manager)*

PC Information

> Microsoft Windows Xp Service Pack 3

Comment: is your device rooted?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to do a factory reset and then try to check out your trouble with Kies.
**Note: Backup all your data before the reset!**

Comment: I strongly doubt a factory reset of the phone will solve the OPs problem. It's more likely just Kies malfunctioning  which happens a lot, it's just not a very solid piece of software.