# My Samsung galaxy ace duos s6802 not getting detected in downloading mode.Drivers are fine Kies installed

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging, samsung, usb-drivers

I have tried [My Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5801) is not being detected by my PC -- What should I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/my-samsung-galaxy-3-gt-i5801-is-not-being-detected-by-my-pc-what-should-i-d) But when I dial *#7284# there is no option to change mode from PDA to Modem or Modem to PDA. Is there any other code to get this working?