# S5 Not Getting Detected On Laptop

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-s-5

so I just got my phone today and had it unlocked. So- it got rooted. I don't think that's the problem though. Anyway I tried to connect it to my laptop and HAZZAH- Nothing happened. It didn't get detected. For a second it was installing the driver then after that nothing happened. All I've been doing for the past 2 hours was uninstall drivers and reinstall them and nothing even happened. Right now I'm just using AirDroid, but since sometimes I don't have WiFi I really need the USB Cable thing to work. No idea what to do anymore. I also tried Kies, and it wasn't detected. Apparently my phone was incompatible. I checked and it was. So that really confused me.

For some reason, when I go to **storage**, it doesn't allow me to go any "menu", since the menu button has now been replaced with a recents tab.

By the way, it shows up in Devices and and Printers as an **unspecified device** and is named **SAMSUNG_Android**. If that is any sort of relevance.

Just to clarify, I've done the following:
1. Restarted my phone AND laptop
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers
3. Changed which USB port it was in
4. Unchecked tethering
5. Enabled USB debugging

If you are to help me and have any knowledge on what to do, or feel like I did it wrong, please let me know how to do so with step by step instructions. Thank you and have a good day everyone!

Comment: possibly related: [My Samsung Galaxy 3 (GT-i5801) is not being detected by my PC — What should I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/my-samsung-galaxy-3-gt-i5801-is-not-being-detected-by-my-pc-what-should-i-d)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is driver problem.

1. Download latest Google USB driver [click here.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. For install driver follow this steps [Installing driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver)

I hope this help you

Comment: Note that step 1 is only for Google devices. For non-Google devices, each manufacturer has its own [OEM USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers) that need to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer could be helpful](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/5067/202272). I expect rooting got nothing to do with it. Samsung connecting to PC been nightmare for me sometimes and specially S3 which was depending totally on the cable.

If I were you I would trace this problem by starting to try the same phone and cable on another machine (pc or laptop) if possible and see if that works. Clearly if it does, the problem in the driver installed or sort of settings mess. If it doesn't, try another cable. Try turning off USB debugging and connecting the device on different machine as well.

Answer (score -1):

get a better quality cable. cheap cables are only good for charging.

Comment: There is no surety that this would work. I think this should be a comment until OP  confirms the case.